# How to use ASP.NET / Razor partials to inject Vue/Webpack bundle into webpack HTML template

Tags: vue.js, webpack, webpack-4, vue-cli-3

I'm attempting to add VueJS into a legacy ASP.NET app. To this I wish to use Razor's `@Html.Partial()` method to inject the CSS and JS files generated by Vue's webpack into the Header and Body of an existing and a complex Razor layout template file used on every page in the legacy app.

To support multiple webpack entry points (mult-page) we're using the [`pages`](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#pages) feature of Vue CLI v3 with the following `vue.config.js` file to goal to generate vendor, common and app webpack chunks.

```js
var fs = require("fs");
var path = require("path");

// Can be Vue App or Shared bundles
var appBasePath = "./src/apps/";

var template = path.resolve(__dirname, "src", "index.razor.ejs");
console.log("template=", template);

var pages = {};
// We search for index.js files inside basePath folder and make those as entries
fs.readdirSync(appBasePath).forEach(function(name) {
  var appMainJS = `${appBasePath}${name}/main.ts`; // entry point
  var outputHtml = `${name}.html`; // partial Head & Body

  console.log(appMainJS);
  console.log(outputHtml);

  if (fs.existsSync(appMainJS)) {
    pages[name] = {
      // entry for the app
      entry: appMainJS,
      // source template  - might be relative to ./public ???
      template,
      // output HMTL
      filename: outputHtml,
      inject: false,
      minify: false,
      // when using title option,
      // template title tag needs to be <title><%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %></title>
      // title: name,
      // chunks to include on this page, by default includes
      // extracted common chunks and vendor chunks.
      chunks: ["chunk-vendors", "chunk-common", "index"], 
    };
  }
});

module.exports = {
  pluginOptions: {
    quasar: {
      treeShake: true
    }
  },
  transpileDependencies: [/[\\\/]node_modules[\\\/]quasar[\\\/]/],
  pages
};
```

The template file `./src/index.razor.ejs` is a webpack template for the [HTML Webpack Plugin](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin) and is intended to emit a Razor partial HTML file that accepts a `true` mobile value to insert the Header tags OR `false` to insert the Body tags.

```
@model System.Boolean

@if(Model)
{
  <% for (var css in htmlWebpackPlugin.files.css) { %>
    <link href="<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.files.css[css] %>" rel="stylesheet">
  <% } %>
} else {
  <% if (htmlWebpackPlugin.options.appMountId) { %>
    <div id="<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.appMountId%>"></div>
    <% } %>

    <% if (htmlWebpackPlugin.options.appMountIds && htmlWebpackPlugin.options.appMountIds.length > 0) { %>
    <% for (var index in htmlWebpackPlugin.options.appMountIds) { %>
    <div id="<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.appMountIds[index]%>"></div>
    <% } %>
    <% } %>

    <% if (htmlWebpackPlugin.options.window) { %>
    <script>
      <% for (var varName in htmlWebpackPlugin.options.window) { %>
        window['<%=varName%>'] = <%= JSON.stringify(htmlWebpackPlugin.options.window[varName]) %>;
      <% } %>
    </script>
    <% } %>

    <% for (var chunk in htmlWebpackPlugin.files.chunks) { %>
    <script src="<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.files.chunks[chunk].entry %>"></script>
    <% } %>

    <% if (htmlWebpackPlugin.options.devServer) { %>
    <script src="<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.devServer%>/webpack-dev-server.js"></script>
    <% } %>
}
```

Due to the required structure of the emitted Razor partial HTML I can't use a traditional HTML file that webpack's [HTML Webpack Plugin](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin) is designed to use. Sadly the template ABOVE will only emit vendor and common chunks.  I've attempted using this alternative template but it emits nothing ...

```js
@model System.Boolean

@if (Model)
{
  <%= htmlWebpackPlugin.headTags %>
} else {
  <%= htmlWebpackPlugin.bodyTags %>
}
```

BTW ... the official example uses `htmlWebpackPlugin.tags.headTags` and `htmlWebpackPlugin.tags.bodyTags` but that throws an exception that `tags` is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

I know it a bit late.. but I have the same problem.

Here is my solution (my .cshtml-templatepage) (combine of multiple files):

```
<% for (var chunk of webpack.chunks) {
for (var file of chunk.files) {
    if (file.match(/\.(js|css)$/)) { %>
<link rel="<%= chunk.initial?'preload':'prefetch' %>" href="<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.files.publicPath + file %>" as="<%= file.match(/\.css$/)?'style':'script' %>">
    <% }
    }
}
_.forEach(htmlWebpackPlugin.files.css, function(file) { %>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<%= file%>" />
<%}); %>

<% _.forEach(htmlWebpackPlugin.files.js, function(file) { %>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= file%>"></script>
<%}); %>
```

1. First I loop though all files in chucks and look for js/css-files to preload or prefetch.
2. Next I render my css-files
3. Finally I render all js-files (this part will not take the prefetched files from part 1, but I don't think it is important for you)